# Unramified morphism of schemes is locally of finite presentation

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, schemes, ramification

Let $f:X\to Y$  be a morphism of schemes and $x\in X$.

Is it true that $f$ unramified in $x\Rightarrow f$ is locally of finite presentation? If yes, I don't see how to prove it?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Presumably you mean "unramified". Typically one takes locally of finite type as part of the definition of unramified, which is equivalent to locally of finite presentation if $Y$ is locally noetherian. Does this resolve your issue?

Comment: Right @KReiser, thank you! I just edited

Comment: Yes it resolved my issue! Thank you!

Comment: Great, I'll post that as an answer to get this out of the unanswered queue.

Comment: Could you please give a reference for the local noetherianity condition ? I couldn't find one

Comment: Sure, I added one to the answer. It's fairly straightforwards.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204437/why-are-unramified-maps-not-required-to-be-locally-of-finite-presentation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An unramified morphism is defined to be locally of finite type, which is equivalent to locally of finite presentation in the case that the target of the morphism is locally noetherian.

Here's a reference for the last fact: [Stacks 01TX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01TX). The proof is standard: a ring map being of finite presentation is equivalent to finite type plus the kernel being finitely generated. As a ring finite type over a noetherian ring is again noetherian and thus has all ideals finitely generated, the result follows after translating from rings to schemes.